# How to open VF page in separate tab or popup window from Aura Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, toast

I have created a VF page which display tooltip information and **I want to display those tooltip in separate window or separate popup window during record creation**. I have referred below link to open VF page from Toast message messageTemplateData link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation

Below is the code that I have tried:

```
showMyToast : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        mode: 'sticky',
        message: 'This is a required message',
        messageTemplate: 'Please Check Tooltip{0} First! & {1}',
        messageTemplateData: ['Salesforce', {
            url: 'https://myorg.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPageName',
            label: 'Click here',
            }
        ]
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

Now when I tested above code, it opens the link within same tab, But I want to open this link in other tab or in separate popup window.If Right Click then it opens in other tab but I want it in single click .If I use **window.open(link,'_blank')** then as soon as Aura component gets launched, it display toast message and at the same time it launches the link in other tab without manually clicking on the link.

```
showMyToast : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        mode: 'sticky',
        message: 'This is a required message',
        messageTemplate: 'Please Check Tooltip{0} First! & {1}',
        messageTemplateData: ['Salesforce', {
            url: window.open('https://myorg.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPageName/','_blank'),
            label: 'Click here',
            }
        ]
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

**If I open any general link then its launching in other tab which is as expected but I am not sure why it's opening the same within same tab when launching VF page.**

Below is the code which open link in other tab.

```
showMyToast : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        mode: 'sticky',
        message: 'This is a required message',
        messageTemplate: 'Record {0} created! See it {1}!',
        messageTemplateData: ['Salesforce', {
            url: 'http://www.salesforce.com/',
            label: 'Click here',
            }
        ]
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

Can someone please suggest how to open VF page in separate tab or in popup window from **Toast Message messageTemplateData** link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of doing that with force:showToast, you can obtain a similar result using the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) or creating a custom toast copying [the SLDS toast blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Problem here is I have lightning Component where I display Next and Cancel button only & Record Type Select. Once I click on Next Button, with e.force:createRecord event ,it navigates to the standard page layout and i want to display those toast message there. Custom Toast message appear only on Aura, not on Standard Pagelyout.

Comment: lightning:overlayLibrary also may not useful as When CreateRecord Page display then only I want to show Toast Message and from the docs, looks like I have to define in aura first and with onclick event, it gets triggered. again with e.force:createRecord, it may not be achievable. Could you please suggest other approach?

Comment: That's a different issue then. Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273670/how-do-i-add-a-toast-message-to-a-standard-salesforce-page-something-like-adder, and remember there's also a Notifications API that may help

Comment: If I create such component and embedded it on my lightning page, will it appear it on Record Create layout? I believe it wont appear and notification API does not work in my case because I don't want to send notification to users. When User try to create record, only then I have to show that toast message which includes specific link of Tooltip.