# Alert on account page for a new note being added

Tags: appexchange, lightning-message-service

I want to be able to create an alert that is displayed on the account page whenever a new note is added. I've seen the Lightning Message Utility managed component in appexchange (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBecDEAT) but after installing it and playing with it in my sandbox it only seems to work for certain fields in a type of boolean statement (if a field holds a certain condition). What I want is to make it work based off of a new note being posted on an account but I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a couple options are outlined in David’s existing answer here:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/273671/10073

Basically you might want to configure a Platform Event to be emitted whenever “Note” is created or updated within an Account. Then using Flow (or Process Builder if its still around) you could display a Custom Notification (bell alert) whenever that Platform Event occurs; with Custom Notifications you can specify the recipients as users, groups, queues and more.

If Custom Notifications are not flexible-enough you could also consider developing a toast message, which David also covers in the link above.

Let us know if this helps or if you choose another approach.